# I'm making a bool condition for search and review cart page

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

I'm making a bool condition for search and review cart page then i face these 3 errors i try to solve but not success(first 2 error on container //Expected to find ','. //The element type 'bool' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. )and the second one on the text widget(Expected to find ']'.)

```
bool isBool = false;
  SigleItem(this.isBool);



 isBool ==false  Container( //Expected to find ','. //The element type 'bool' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  height: 35,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'RS-799',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          size: 20,
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ):Text('750')//Expected to find ']'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the question mark after bool condition, read [this](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/ternary-conditional-operator) for `Conditional Statement`

```
isBool == false
        ? Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            height: 35,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'RS-799',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : Text('750'),
```

Result Screen->[image]

Comment: thnaks broo for your help

Comment: @HassanNaveed happy to help you, enjoy your ride with flutter

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the use question mark. You need to use like this.

```
isBool == false ? Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  height: 35,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'RS-799',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          size: 20,
                          color: primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ):Text('750'),
```

Comment: yes,i forgot the question mark.thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use ternary operator like this

> **isBool ?** text("if true then show this") **:** text("if false then show this)

boool_var ? true_widget : false_widget